# what is the difference between providing 7 volts or 12 volts to arduino uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

according to [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) the recommended input voltage is between 7 and 12 volts.
The question is what is the difference between providing 7 volts(minimum recommended volts) and 12 volts(maximum recommended volts) ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of heat dissipated by the voltage regulator.  The higher the voltage you supply the hotter the regulator will get.

Comment: I agree with Majenko. A higher voltage will make the voltage regulator run hotter, particularly if you are drawing a lot of current (eg. to power LEDs or similar). However since you probably won't find a 7V wall-wart, they give you a range of voltages that are acceptable.